# Xcode 7.1.1 opens up as Xcode 7.0.1

Tags: xcode

I updated my Xcode to 7.1.1 (it said so in the Mac App Store).

When I click on "Open", Xcode 7.0.1 showed up instead of Xcode 7.1.1.

Do I need OSX El Capitan to run Xcode 7.1.1 ?

In the past, I had Xcode 7.1 Beta 2 installed, I wonder if that caused some files to be corrupted.

Seems like someone else had a similar problem here: [Updated XCode to 7.0.1 via the app store but it still shows itself at 6.4 in the app and missing the new features](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/211718/updated-xcode-to-7-0-1-via-the-app-store-but-it-still-shows-itself-at-6-4-in-the)

The answer there recommended deleting all copies of Xcode and reinstall from scratch.

I'll download OS X El Capitan to see if it fixes it before I decide to nuke Xcode to oblivion on my computer and redownload it all again

### Update 1:

Updated my laptop to Mac OS X El Capitan but didn't fix it either. Xcode still start up as Xcode 7.0.1 =/

I guess it's time to nuke Xcode.

Comment: Could you try consolidating all your comments into one coherent question, which includes what you have tried so far & what the results were.

Comment: If you do "Get Info" on `/Applications/Xcode.app`, which version number is displayed?

Comment: @patrix if you're talking about the Apple Icon > About Xcode it shows up as Xcode 7.0.1.

Comment: I'm not, I'm talking about finding Xcode.app in Finder (which usually means opening the Application folder) and typing Cmd-I.

Comment: I don't know who the cowards are who keeps down voting. The original question was perfectly valid and legitimate. If you're going to down vote, give a reason because not doing so isn't helping.

Comment: Had the same issue just know. Removing XCode from the app folder and reinstalling via App Store worked for me. Probably some issue with the app store?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are tired downloading Xcode from the App Store or searching for old Xcode.apps somewhere hidden on your volumes, go to [Developer Apple Downloads](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/), enter a valid Apple ID and password and download *[Xcode 7.1.1.dmg (direct link)](http://adcdownload.apple.com/Developer_Tools/Xcode_7.1.1/Xcode_7.1.1.dmg)* and any other tool you need to code or debug.

Remove any Xcode.app in your /Applications folder, open the dmg and copy Xcode to your /Applications folder.

Comment: Yeah, it's probably better if I download the DMG directly from Apple rather than going through the Mac App Store, especially when I have multiple Mac computers, better than downloading twice :) It doesn't help when logging into Apple's iOS Developer Center and the download link for Xcode 7.1.1 DMG says "View in Mac App Store". They like to bury the link to download so developers can't find it, forcing them to use the Mac App Store instead.

Comment: Deleting Xcode from Applications folder and manually installing the Xcode 7.1.1 dmg did the trick. I'll bookmark that Apple developer direct download link.